# How to include an asciidoc file into sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, asciidoc

Sometimes you need to insert doc from third parties. For example: https://github.com/riscv/riscv-plic-spec/blob/master/riscv-plic.adoc

I could manually translate that one to rst but obviously it would be better if the tools can do it already. As an example, with HTML, I can use `.. raw: html`

Comment: Is the file an HTML page? If so, then use `..raw:: html` with an `iframe`. If not, what do you want to do with the remote page?

Comment: @Piercy the question is about asciidoc file. So that means the asciidoc would be converted to rst or to the output format directly by sphinx

Comment: I am not aware of any AsciiDoc parser/plugin that works with Sphinx (similar to MyST for Markdown). Perhaps you can use Pandoc to convert from AsciiDoc to RST.